# How to create a Slider with dynamic counting Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

How to create a Slider as shown in Attached image

[image]

Comment: See [Xamarin.Forms Slider](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/slider) to get a general idea about sliders. For the custom appearance, you will have to code a custom slider on your own.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this  [Custom Slider Nuget Package](https://github.com/sumeyyaarar/XamarinFormsCustomSlider)

Comment: Your slider is looking good but I want to add numbers into sliding thumps. Like attached image. "2 km"  showing on thump